# Groupby on custom column and time with SQL

Tags: sql, aggregation, metabase

I have a following dataset:

| collection_time | col_a | col_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-27 14:15 | 20 | 15 |
| 2022-06-27 14:13 | -1 | -1 |
| 2022-06-26 20:15 | 21 | 47 |

I would like to have the following output:

| collection_time | count_negatives | count_positives |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-27 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-06-26 | 0 | 1 |

I was trying to use `CASE WHEN expr THEN val ELSE val END` syntax, combined with `GROUP BY collection_time, count_negatives, count_posivites` but I haven't had any luck so far.

It's difficult for me to even share any sort of queries as nothing gives me any sort of useful results.
Can anybody help me out a little bit with that?

Comment: You cannot use a custom column name in `group by`, you can only use it in `order by`. But why do you `group by count_negatives, count_posivites` those columns look like they're from a `count()`?

Comment: O, you are right! Using count(exp) was enough! Thanks!